# How to code auto key cipher in python?

Tags: python

Can somebody help me write the auto_key cipher in python. I understand   the logic but don't know how to start.I wrote the code but it didn't work this is my auto_key cipher code, when I run it gives me the new 
key if key is less than message. and then stops there, it doesn't work.thank you!

```
enter code here
ALPHA = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
def main():
    message = input('enter message:\n')
    key = input('enter your key:\n')
    mode = input('encrypt or decrypt\n')
    if len(key) < len(message):
        key = key[0:] + message[:100]
    #print(key)
    if mode == 'encrypt':
       cipher = encryptMessage(message, key)

    elif mode == 'decrypt':
       cipher = decryptMessage(message, key)
    #print(' message:',  (mode.title()))
    print(cipher)
def encryptMessage (keys, messages):
    return cipherMessage(keys, messages, 'encrypt')
def decryptMessage(keys,messages):
    return cipherMessage(keys, messages, 'decrypt')
def cipherMessage (keys, messages, mode):
    cipher = []
    k_index = 0
    key = keys.upper()
    for i in messages:
        text = ALPHA.find(i.upper())
        if text != -1:
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                 text += ALPHA.find(key[k_index])


            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                 text -= ALPHA.find(key[k_index])
            text %= len(ALPHA)
            k_index += -1
            if k_index == len(key):
                k_index = 0
       else:
           cipher.append(i)
    return ''.join(cipher)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Comment: `cipher` is empty at the end of cipher message ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I didn't get it could you please elaborate it? thanks!

Comment: What @JoranBeasley means is that `cipher.append(i)` will never be reached, but, even it would be possible to reach that point, it would append  the wrong character. When in encription-mode it would append a cleartext character and in decription mode it would append a cipher character.
Have you ever tested the single parts of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I fixed your code I recommend you start all over again.
Your code is a mess! :D
It works now, but it will still fail if the input does not fit, the logic you implemented.

---

Let's go:

- Lines 8-9:
  Useless at this point!
  *Note: What would happen `if len(key) == 5 and len(message) == 130`?*
- Line 16-17, 18-19 and 20:
  In line 10 and 13 you call `function(message, key)`, but here you 
  call:

  ```
  def function((keys, messages)):
      return cipherMessage((keys, messages), 'encrypt')
  ```

  You switched message and key, that was the reason for the IndexError.
- Line 26:
  Useless in this for-loop
- Line 34:
  `k_index` must be increased!
- Line 35-37:

  - this `if` is useless in this for-loop
  - this `else:` is the reason `cipher.append(i)` is never reached
- Line 38:
  To `cipher` you need to add the shortly encrypted/decrypted char , **not** the 
  char form `message`

Fixing all that, you'll get the below code.

*Note: comments with `##` indicate what I commented out of your code.*

---

```
ALPHA = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def main():
    message = input('enter message:\n')
    key = input('enter your key:\n')
    mode = input('encrypt or decrypt\n')
    ## if len(key) < len(message):
        ## key = key[0:] + message[:100]
    #print(key)
    if mode == 'encrypt':
       cipher = encryptMessage(message, key)
    elif mode == 'decrypt':
       cipher = decryptMessage(message, key)
    #print(' message:',  (mode.title()))
    print(cipher)


## def encryptMessage (keys, messages):
##     return cipherMessage(keys, messages, 'encrypt')
  def encryptMessage (messages, keys):  
    return cipherMessage(messages, keys, 'encrypt')


## def decryptMessage(keys,messages):
##     return cipherMessage(keys, messages, 'decrypt')
def decryptMessage(messages, keys):
    return cipherMessage(messages, keys, 'decrypt')


## def cipherMessage (keys, messages, mode):
def cipherMessage (messages, keys, mode):
    cipher = []
    k_index = 0
    key = keys.upper()
    for i in messages:
        text = ALPHA.find(i.upper())
        ## if text != -1:
        if mode == 'encrypt':
             text += ALPHA.find(key[k_index])
             key += i.upper()  # add current char to keystream

        elif mode == 'decrypt':
             text -= ALPHA.find(key[k_index])
             key += ALPHA[text]  # add current char to keystream
        text %= len(ALPHA)
        ## k_index += -1
        k_index += 1
        ## if k_index == len(key):
        ##     k_index = 0
        ## else:
        cipher.append(ALPHA[text])
    return ''.join(cipher)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @ DahliaSR, Thank you!